# splitting a string using '\0'

Tags: c, string

let's say I have a char* `./a.out\0a\0b\0\0`.
I want to split it and the result to be a char** of value

```
{
    "./a.out\0",
    "a\0",
    "b\0",
    "\0"
}
```

I'm using pure c + POSIX but if an answer contains parts of the c++STL I don't mind that, just avoid the memory inefficient ones like std::string

Comment: C or C++? They are two *very* different languages, and the solution would look very different depending on language. Please pick one, the one you're actually programming in.

Comment: Likely this would be a challenge without doing it yourself since strings are null terminated

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like showing us a [mre] of *your own* attempt together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: c and c++. as I said I don't mind if you use a bit of the STL but I would prefer the code to be pure c.

Comment: Since nul is being used to delimit tokens in the string, it cannot be used as a marker to avoid running off the end of storage. You will need at least one more piece of information to accomplish this safely.

Comment: You didn't understand the question, or just don't want to answer it. Regardless, hopefully the prospect `char*` sequence ends with a double-terminator (consecutive, uninterrupted terminators), Otherwise, the answer is you don't, as you have no way of knowing where the edge of the flat earth lays. A splitter in either language would be fairly mundane, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: yeah it is double terminated. or atleast I can easily make it to be double terminated

Comment: Interesting that you want to avoid `std::string`. It's designed to handle this pretty much out of the box.

Comment: I don't think it can split strings. and I'm also avoiding it for performance

Comment: What is your *exact* assignment or exercise? What limitations and requirements does it have? And if you prefer a "pure C" solution, then please stick to that and tag only that language. Tagging multiple vastly different languages tend to make people skip your questions. And without any attempt of your own that will turn away many of the others.

Comment: just added some information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to populate an array of pointers from your composite string, assuming you know how many strings are adjacent:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *str = "./a.out\0a\0b\0";  // 3 strings
    const char *args[3];

    const char *p = str;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        args[i] = p;
        p += strlen(p) + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("args[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, args[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
args[0] = "./a.out"
args[1] = "a"
args[2] = "b"
```

Here is an alternative encapsulated as a function that allocates an array, scanning the byte array to determine the number of strings, relying on 2 consecutive null bytes to indicate the end of the list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char **split(const char *str) {
    const char **array;
    const char *p;
    int count = 0, i;

    // count the number of strings
    for (p = str; *p; p += strlen(p) + 1) {
        count++;
    }
    // allocate the array with an extra element for a NULL terminator
    array = calloc(sizeof(*array), count + 1);
    if (array != NULL) {
        // populate the array with pointers into the string
        for (i = 0, p = str; i < count; i++, p += strlen(p) + 1) {
            array[i] = p;
        }
        // set the NULL terminator
        array[i] = NULL;
    }
    return array;
}

int main() {
    const char *str = "./a.out\0a\0b\0";  // 4 strings
    const char **args = split(str);

    for (int i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("args[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, args[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
args[0] = "./a.out"
args[1] = "a"
args[2] = "b"
```

Comment: I don't know how many strings are adjacent

Comment: @MaxCE Then you have a very big problem: How would you detect the end of the string? Does it have a double-null-terminator without anything in between?

Comment: I said it earlier in the main comment thread. it is double terminated.

Comment: @MaxCE Crucial information, requirements, and limitations should all be part of the main question body itself.